# Error in a FOREIGN KEY constraint that i not called

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Tecnologies: ASP.Net MVC 3, Entity Framework 4, SQL Server 2012.

When i try insert a new entity in my database, the entity framework gives that error:

```
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Cep_Cidade". The conflict occurred in database "CloudWorkLJEletro", table "dbo.Cidade", column 'ID'.
The statement has been terminated.
```

The problem is that table dbo.Cidade or any association with this table is not called in my operation. Why do I get this error if I'm not performing any operation on this table or in your relationships.

Database scheme:
[image]

And My code:

```
        public void SaveContrato(Contrato Contrato, int id)
        {
            try
            {

                Contrato.Endereco = null;
                Contrato.ID_ENDERECO = null;

                context.AddToContrato(Contrato);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }  
        }
```

Comment: Please do not use `throw ex`; that throws away the stack trace of the exception and says `SaveContrato` threw the exception.

Comment: But if remove, the problem continues with the same issue.